# AWS Greengrass lambda deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to deploy a lambda function with greengrass device basically EC2.

Deployment was successful and the lambda function is triggering with the IOT publish event as I want.

But as I can check in logs whenever I published messages on the IOT topic to invoke lambda function, I am getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] (Thread-3) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Somehow got message from topic that no one subscribed to.
```